# Building web app using justpy, program showing no output

Tags: python, error-handling, justpy

Working on building a web app using justpy. Can't seem to find out what the problem is.

Here's the code:-

```
import justpy as jp

def app(): 
    wp=jp.QuasarPage
    h1=jp.QDiv(a=wp, text= "Analysis of Course Reviews" ,classes= "text-h2 text-weight-medium red text-center")
    p1=jp.QDiv(a=wp,text="These graphs represent course review analysis") 

    return wp

    jp.justpy(app)
```

Not getting any output or errors on running program. Here's a screenshot of the terminal:

Terminal SS:

[image: Terminal SS]

Answer (score 1):

```py
import justpy as jp

def app(): 
    wp=jp.QuasarPage()
    h1=jp.QDiv(a=wp, text= "Analysis of Course Reviews" ,classes= "text-h2 
 text-weight-medium red text-center")
    p1=jp.QDiv(a=wp,text="These graphs represent course review analysis") 

    return wp

jp.justpy(app)
```

The above code works